# #Requires doesn't see the module, Import-Module works

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-module

When I run a simple script with `#Requires -Version 4 -Modules TestModule` statement at the first line, I get an error:

> The script 'TestScript.ps1' cannot be run because the following
>   modules that are specified by the "#requires" statements of the script
>   are missing: TestModule
>              CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (TestScript.ps1:String) [], ScriptRequiresException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   ScriptRequiresMissingModules

Some interesting facts:

1. The second time I run this script (same session), the module is loaded and everything works.
2. Script directory is on a network share, but 7 other modules load without any problems (module types are Manifest, Script and Binary - they all worlk).
3. One of the modules also has `#Requires -Version 4 -Modules TestModule` statement, but when I run a script with `#Requires` pointing to that module, both modules are loaded without any problems.
4. Path is obviously added to `PSModulePath`.
5. Prior to running the script, `Get-Module -ListAvailable` does list TestModule and all its' commands.
6. `Import-Module` works the first time.
7. There may be something missing on the machine: anyone who logs on that computer is experiencing the same problem.

`$PSVersionTable`:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.18444
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.16406
```

I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: are you loading the module before you run the script?

Comment: @Luke No. `#Requires` is supposed to load the module. But if I load the module before I run the script, it works fine.

Comment: So according to Microsoft "If the required modules are not in the current session, Windows PowerShell imports them. If the modules cannot be imported, Windows PowerShell throws a terminating error." which is what I think you are asking about? correct, why isn't it importing it automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the reason. 
I replaced `#Requires` with `Import-Module TestModule -Verbose` and found out that one of the assemblies could not be loaded, generating an error, but due to `$ErrorActionPreference=Continue` the rest of the module loaded. It appears that `#Requires` behaves differently than `Import-Module`.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason an error like this is that your parameters have incorrect options. For me, having a parameter with an empty `HelpMessage=""` string caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I received this error when trying to specify two modules on the same line:

```
#Requires -Modules Module1, Module2
```

To resolve, I separated them out into multiple statements:

```
#Requires -Modules Module1
#Requires -Modules Module2
```

Despite Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_requires?view=powershell-5.1) showing that you should be able to list multiple modules in the same statement.